# LDAP authentication on Apache for Mercurial

Tags: apache, mercurial, ldap

To set up LDAP authentication with SVN+Apache is relatively easy: you use `AuthzSVNAccessFile` directive in Apache config to specify groups and users.

Is there a way to do the same for Mercurial+Apache?

Comment: `AuthzSVNAccessFile` **does not correlate** with LDAP at all

Comment: Try [this article](https://www.icts.uiowa.edu/confluence/display/ICTSit/Mercurial+hgweb+configuration)

Comment: @LazyBadger: you're right, `AuthzSVNAccessFile` is unrelated. I was searching for a non-existing thing. Thanks.